# Как получить словарь с конкретным значением ключа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеются такие словари, полученные циклом:

```
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0}
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1}
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0}
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1}
```

Нужно получить словари, которые имеют 'online' со значением 1. При этом, чтобы возвращались целые словари, т.е. с first_name и last_name, а не просто  'online': 1. Пробовал делать так:

```
    for search in dict:
        if 'online' == 1 in search:
            print(search)
```

Но результата никакого не дало.

Comment: Имеются такие словари где? Как и в какие переменные вы их получили?

Comment: @andreymal через vk api: dict = vk_session.method('users.get', {'user_ids': user_ids), 'fields': 'online'})

Comment: Вот покажите нам print(dict)

Comment: @andreymal print(dict) выведет то, что я написал в вопросе

Comment: Он вообще никак не может вывести то, что вы написали в вопросе. Вы написали четыре отдельных словаря, а dict это строго один объект

Comment: @andreymal да если и вывести один dict, то получится один массив, который имеет внутри эти же несколько словарей отделённых через запятую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = [
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1},
]

# Фильтр
new_items = [data for data in items if data['online']]
for data in new_items:
    print(data)

# Или без создания нового списка:
for data in items:
    if data['online']:
        print(data)
```

Консоль:

```
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1}
{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pprint import pprint

dl = [
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 0},
    {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1},
]

pprint([*filter(lambda x: x.get('online'), dl)])
# [{'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1},
#  {'first_name': 'Иван', 'last_name': 'Иванов', 'online': 1}]
```